# Count users on date if not exists in another list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am counting the users on the required date. I have a nested `dict(named as b)` and `list(named as c)`. In list, I have some users. By Comparing the users in list, I want to count the users of date in b. If the user is there in `list (c)`, it should not be counted. I succeeded by counting the users of given date.

But now, my problem is, if the user already exists in the before date in `b`, it should not be counted. I don't how to make it possible. Help me with some solutions. For example, in date `2019-10-12`,user named prince already exists in date `2019-10-11` and user named ram is in `list(c)`.so it should be counted as 0. But in my case, I get the value 1

```
b = {'2019-10-10': {'sam': 1, 'maha': 1}, '2019-10-11': {'sam': 1, 'prince': 1, 'kumar': 1, 'jeba': 1}, '2019-10-12': {'ram': 1, 'prince': 1}, '2019-10-13': {'raja': 1, 'peer': 1}}


c = ['sam', 'ram', 'king', 'queen', 'kumar', 'jeba', 'howl']
f ={}
for i in b:
    for j in b[i]:
        if j not in c: 
            if i not in f:
                f[i]=1
            else:
                f[i]=f[i]+1
        else:
            if i not in f:
                f[i]=0
print(f)
```

My Output:

```
{'2019-10-10': 1, '2019-10-11': 1, '2019-10-12': 1, '2019-10-13': 2}
```

Required:

```
{'2019-10-10': 1, '2019-10-11': 1, '2019-10-12': 0, '2019-10-13': 2}
```

Comment: Based on your whishes, I don't get why you require `'2019-10-12': 0`? 'ram' is in the list, but 'prince' isn't. So `1` should be the good output right?

Comment: As far as I am understanding, OP want's a "newly occurring user" to be added into `c` as the time goes. So a user can be new only once!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
b={'2019-10-10': {'sam': 1, 'maha': 1}, '2019-10-11': {'sam': 1, 'prince': 1, 'kumar': 1, 'jeba': 1}, '2019-10-12': {'ram': 1, 'prince': 1}, '2019-10-13': {'raja': 1, 'peer': 1}}
c=['ram', 'maha', 'kumar', 'raja', 'prince', 'queen', 'king', 'peer', 'jeba', 'howl', 'sam']
sorted_keys = list(b.keys())
sorted_keys.sort() # sort keys in ascending order of date
d={k:0 for k in b} # initialise d dict
last_seen=[]  # last seen element 

for k in sorted_keys:
    for k1 in b[k]:
        if k1 not in c and k1 not in last_seen:
            d[k]+=1;last_seen.append(k1)
print(d)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by @Saharsh already answers in an easy way. But I would recommend to use more appropiate types for each instance.

Times should be stored in `datetime.date`, if the order of a dict matters you have `collections.OrderedDict` (it does not sort the keys, it keeps them in the same order than you entered them into the dict) and if you want to keep a list of already known users you should use a `set`.

## Dates

First lets check how to convert date strings into date objects

```py
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.strptime('2019-10-10', '%Y-%m-%d')
print(type(date), date) # <class 'datetime.datetime'> 2019-10-10 00:00:00
date = date.date()
print(type(date), date) # <class 'datetime.date'> 2019-10-10
```

The `strptime` method of the `datetime` class inside the `datetime` module (yes, module and class have the same name) will provide you a `datetime` object which contains both the date and time information. As we only care about the date we can use the `date` method to extract the date as an instance of the `date` class. This `datetime` and `date` objects can be used as keys for our `dict`s.

## Sorted dicts

Now lets see how a `OrderedDict` works:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict()
d[3] = 1
d[2] = 2
d[5] = 3
d[1] = 0
print(d) # OrderedDict([(3, 1), (2, 2), (5, 3), (1, 0)])
```

The dict is not printed as pretty as the others but it works exactly as a normal dict except that it guanrantees that the insertion order is mantained. While this may seem trivial, the normal dict has no guarantee that this will happen, you nay get the `1=>0` pair before the `5=>3` while iterating. In our case this matters as every date has to be processed chronologically.

## Sets

Sets are like lists but they can not contain duplicate items and they provide some extra methods for common set operations such as unions or differences.

```py
c = {'sam', 'ram', 'king', 'queen', 'kumar', 'jeba', 'howl'}
```

A set is as simple as using curly brackets (`{}`) instead of square brackets (`[]`).

## Full solution

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
from datetime import datetime

visitors = OrderedDict()
visitors[datetime.strptime('2019-10-10', '%Y-%m-%d').date()] = {'sam', 'maha'}
visitors[datetime.strptime('2019-10-11', '%Y-%m-%d').date()] = {'sam', 'prince', 'kumar', 'jeba'}
visitors[datetime.strptime('2019-10-12', '%Y-%m-%d').date()] = {'ram', 'prince'}
visitors[datetime.strptime('2019-10-13', '%Y-%m-%d').date()] = {'raja', 'peer'}

known_visitors = {'sam', 'ram', 'king', 'queen', 'kumar', 'jeba', 'howl'}

new_visitors_count = OrderedDict()
for date, visited in visitors.items():
    new_visitors = visited.difference(known_visitors)
    known_visitors = known_visitors.union(new_visitors)
    new_visitors_count[date] = len(new_visitors)

print(new_visitors_count)
```

The `visitors` `OrderedDict` is the equivalent to your `b` `dict` while the `known_visitors` `set` is equivalent to your `c` `list`. As you can see I also removed the `1`s from `visitors` turning the inner `dict`s into `set`s but you can keep them if they provide any info by changing the first line inside the loop to `new_visitors = set(visited).difference(known_visitors)`.

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
from datetime import datetime

visitors = OrderedDict()
visitors[datetime.strptime('2019-10-10', '%Y-%m-%d').date()] = {'sam': 1, 'maha': 1}
visitors[datetime.strptime('2019-10-11', '%Y-%m-%d').date()] = {'sam': 1, 'prince': 1, 'kumar': 1, 'jeba': 1}
visitors[datetime.strptime('2019-10-12', '%Y-%m-%d').date()] = {'ram': 1, 'prince': 1}
visitors[datetime.strptime('2019-10-13', '%Y-%m-%d').date()] = {'raja': 1, 'peer': 1}

known_visitors = {'sam', 'ram', 'king', 'queen', 'kumar', 'jeba', 'howl'}

new_visitors_count = OrderedDict()
for date, visited in visitors.items():
    new_visitors = set(visited).difference(known_visitors)
    known_visitors = known_visitors.union(new_visitors)
    new_visitors_count[date] = len(new_visitors)

print(new_visitors_count)
```

Loop explanation:
What we are doing is first obtain the difference of the `visited` `set` that are the ones that visited each day with the `known_visitors` that are those that have already visited previously. Basically this means substract the already known ones from each days. Then we update the already known ones so that next days will take those into consideration. And last we update the count of the corresponding date by computing the length of the `visited` `set`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the new user to your known user's array once an unknown user arrives. I have used union operation for this.

```
b = {'2019-10-10': {'sam': 1, 'maha': 1}, '2019-10-11': {'sam': 1, 'prince': 1, 'kumar': 1, 'jeba': 1}, '2019-10-12': {'ram': 1, 'prince': 1}, '2019-10-13': {'raja': 1, 'peer': 1}}
c = ['sam', 'ram', 'king', 'queen', 'kumar', 'jeba', 'howl']
visit = {}
k = list(b.keys())
k.sort()

for i in k:
    x = set(b[i].keys()).difference(set(c))
    visit[i]=len(x)
    c = list(set(c).union(x))
print(visit)
```

This gives:

```
{'2019-10-10': 1, '2019-10-11': 1, '2019-10-12': 0, '2019-10-13': 2}
```

**Edit:** Sorted date occurrence.

Comment: Remember that the dict may not (and probably will not) be ordered.

Comment: @Adirio, thanks for reminding. Updated the code with a sort.